# Object to Object mapping framework

Tags: mapping, automapper

I was interested in any framework/patterns to leverage to generate an object to object Mapping tool.  My goal is to use EF to hydrate the object, and I would like to use a custom class which would define the transformation between ObjectA --> ObjectB (Similar to AutoMapper, Biztalk map yet in .net).  I would think this would be a common scenario and would like to leverage any best practices/frameworks any one has used in the past.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at this tool : [Automapper Verbatim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8471ac38-5b35-41fc-bdbe-78a472d123e1). It's not the same as the Automappper you'd find on Codeplex. Unlike the one on Codeplex, [Automapper Verbatim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8471ac38-5b35-41fc-bdbe-78a472d123e1) will generate code rather than using reflection (it's much more faster).
Updates/Bug fixes seem to be posted on a regular basis.
We use this tool on several projects and it saves us a lot of time.
Some piece of advice though: do not hesitate to split your mapper in different .map files (for performance and readability reasons), putting them in the same directory will let you re-use mapping done from one file to another. Splitting .map files will avoid you merge issues as well (if you work in a team). Be sure to always get the latest version of .map file you'll need to work on, unless merging will become a nightmare :-)